# What does "Geht es auch" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

From studio d A1 page 86:

> Nächste Woche Montag um 9 Uhr 30?
>
> Hm, da kann ich nicht, da arbeite ich. Geht es auch 15 Uhr?
>
> Ja, das geht auch.

What does "Geht es auch" mean in this sentence?

Comment: I actually agree with close voters that this is general reference. I didn't vote for close and instead answered because "gehen" has so many definitions that it is indeed a bit difficult to find it, especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: "Geht es auch *um* 15 Uhr", muss es m.E. heißen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gehen) definition 11:

> funktionieren, machbar sein

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehen#Bedeutung10a) definition 10a:

> sich machen lassen; möglich sein

---

*Gehen* in that sense is likely translated as *to work*.

> Does 3 PM work for you?
>   Yes, that works for me.

Answer (score 4):

*Etwas geht* is another way of saying *etwas ist möglich* (*something is possible*).

Answer (score 0):

"Geht es auch 15 Uhr?" is not at all unusual in colloquial German, but I would consider it slightly improper. It feels like a blend of the following more correct questions:

> Geht es auch um 15 Uhr? - Literal translation: Does it [= the appointment we are in the process of making] also work at 3 p.m.?
>
> Geht auch 15 Uhr? - Literal translation: Does 3 p.m. also work?

In reality, "Geht es auch 15 Uhr?" is probably not a blend, though, but is the result of dropping *um* in the variant "Geht es auch um 15 Uhr?". In informal speech, *um* can sometimes dropped when indicating an hour. This is very similar to how *at* can sometimes be dropped when indicating an hour in English - not just formally but also in terms of usage restrictions and connotations.

Answer (score -1):

It should be *Geht es auch 15 Uhr?*, i e there should be a question mark. It means *Does 3 pm work, too?*